# Resin: How to Get Current Log Directory From in *.xml files

Tags: logging, directory, resin

Suppose I start Resin with a command line option (i.e. --log-directory) to specify my custom log directory, and now some xml files want to reference this alternate log directory.

My question is: is there a predefined EL variable (${sth}) for this? 
Just as ${__DIR__} means current directory.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. Resin doesn't set a log-directory variable. But you can use the -D option instead and resolve from that.

Comment: I found myself in a embarrassing situation: I set the alternate log directory, and now I need to use -D option to use/reference it.

Comment: Well, remember that log path can also be resolved from the same -D option. So that way you only specify the parameter once resolving it in resin.xml for log@path and your other uses.

Comment: Im truly sorry to bother you that much. Where in resin.xml (or other files) can I change/specify the directory for **jvm-myapp-0.log** and **watchdog-manager.log**.

I couldn't find it. That's why I have to set **--log-directory** variable just for the above two files, while using **-D option** to specify a directory for other log files.  

My ultimate goal is to put all the log files into the same directory/folder.

Comment: It's configured in log-handler@path line 17 of default configuration in resin 4.0.42.